# C++ <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, sfml

Im trying to run a project with SFML in VSCode but I get this error:

```
g++  -o app -Llib -lopenal32 -lsfml-system -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -s
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: no se puede encontrar -lopenal32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: no se puede encontrar -lsfml-system
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: no se puede encontrar -lsfml-graphics
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: no se puede encontrar -lsfml-window
collect2: error: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
make: *** [Makefile:17: app] Error 1
```

It seems that cant find the files but
All files .dll are in the same folder than main.cpp, and it is the `setting.json`

```
"C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "C:/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
    "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "C:/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/SFML"
    ],
```

And I get it when g++ -c main.cpp

```
g++ -c main.cpp
main.cpp:1:10: error fatal: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
```

If anyone can help me with it. Thanks!

Comment: You need to edit your makefile properly.

Comment: Have you tried to add `-L.` when compiling?

Comment: include is for header files, library path is for dlls

Comment: You have -Llib, this means dlls should be in a folder named "lib".

Comment: You seem to be mixing compilers. You have mingw and cygwin.

Comment: g++ -c main.cpp
main.cpp:1:10: error fatal: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

I got this

How can i fix it with two compilers? @drescherjm

Comment: I think you need to setup your `tasks.json` file and perhaps get the cygwin folder out of your PATH environment variable. The instructions from Visual Studio Code on how to use mingw on windows are here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)